# How to get name of previous ViewController when switching TabBar Item

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbaritem

In case I have 4 items in Tabar.

When open app, default is in TabBarItem[0] - ViewControllerRoot
I push from ViewControllerRoot into ViewController A. From ViewController A, I switch to TabBarItem[3] - contain ViewController B.

The question is: How can I get name of ViewController A when I switch to TabBarItem[3]?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Are you embedding navigation controller in tabbar controller?

Comment: If your inside ViewController A the name of it is ViewController A. This question isn't clear. Are you automatically switching to TabBarItem[3] once you land on ViewController A or once your on ViewController A you manually press the 4th tab and switch to it?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I want to get name of ViewController A when/before I switch from ViewController A to TabBarItem[3]. I edited the original post.

Comment: @SuganyaMarlin yes i embeded navigation controller in tabbar controller

Answer (score 4):

You can get your current viewcontroller using selectedViewController.

User delegate method of tabbar.

```
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController :UITabBarController, shouldSelect: UIViewController){
let currentVC = tabBarController.selectedViewController
let destinationVC = shouldSelect
}
```

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the view from UITabBar there is a delegate method that is invoked

```
tabBarController:animationControllerForTransitionFromViewController:toViewController:
```

This will help you to find the previous selected controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear..please share some code.

- if you wish to get an the instance of ViewController A: 
  `window.rootViewController?.childViewControllers[0]`
- if you wish to get the class name of ViewController A:

`a = window.rootViewController?.childViewControllers[0]
var className: String = a.self`